# how to increase custom post value by one most efficiently?

Tags: php, custom-field, post-meta

I have a custom post type (created with cmb2) which always contains a number (can be zero as well).

Some times i need to increase it by one with php, so i do this:

```
$value = (int) get_post_meta($post->ID,'myfieldkey',true); $value++; update_post_meta($post->ID,'myfieldkey', $value);
```

i guess i can make it a little shorter by doing this:

```
$value = (int) get_post_meta($post->ID,'myfieldkey',true); update_post_meta($post->ID,'myfieldkey', ++$value);
```

But still it seems to me like a very long code for this simple need.

**My question is:**
Is there a shorter more efficient way to the same thing?
(i am doing the same thing to multiple fields at the same time sometimes so it will really help me decrease the amount of code i'm using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Enter `WP_Post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) and the "magic" getter - did you know...

```
$value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'custom_field', true );
```

...is the same as

```
$value = $post->custom_field;
```

So you can shorten your code to:

```
update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'custom_field', $post->custom_field + 1 );
```

Note you *cannot* do `$post->custom_field++` - since the property doesn't actually exist, it can't be modified. Read more about [overloading in PHP](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members).

Comment: Amazing! that's exactly the kind of solution i was looking for! Thank you very much!